# How to force update a view

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, view, observablecollection

I have an application which contains two `Views` and a `ViewModel`.
The first `View[AddView]` is used for creating objects and the `second[ShowView]` is used for showing the objects. The `ViewModel[DummyData]` consists of an `ObservableCollection` and everything needed for the creation of new objects.

My problem is this:
How to force update `ShowView` when I add object from the `AddView`

Here is the DummyData

```
#region Fake Database
    private static ObservableCollection<Student> fakeStudentDataLayer;

    public UserDummyData()
    {
        fakeStudentDataLayer = new ObservableCollection<Student>()
        {
            new Student(){Name = "test1", Surname = "surnameTest1", Age = 22, Barcode = "testbarcode1", ClassLetter = 'A', ClassNumber = 6, ID = 1, ParentName = "parentTest1", ParentSurname = "ParentSurnameTitle1", Number = 22, DateOfCreation = new DateTime(2008, 12, 2), LastCheckIn = new DateTime(2014, 3, 9)},
            new Student(){Name = "test2", Surname = "surnameTest2", Age = 22, Barcode = "testbarcode2", ClassLetter = 'B', ClassNumber = 8, ID = 2, ParentName = "parentTest2", ParentSurname = "ParentSurnameTitle2", Number = 22, DateOfCreation = new DateTime(2008, 12, 2), LastCheckIn = new DateTime(2014, 3, 9)},
            new Student(){Name = "test3", Surname = "surnameTest3", Age = 22, Barcode = "testbarcode3", ClassLetter = 'C', ClassNumber = 10, ID = 3, ParentName = "parentTest3", ParentSurname = "ParentSurnameTitle3", Number = 22, DateOfCreation = new DateTime(2008, 12, 2), LastCheckIn = new DateTime(2014, 3, 9) }
        };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Student> FakeStudentDataLayer
    {
        get { return fakeStudentDataLayer; }
        set { fakeStudentDataLayer = value; RaisePropertyChanged("FakeStudentDataLayer"); }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Commands
    private RelayCommand _addStudentCommand;
    public ICommand NewStudentCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _addStudentCommand
                ?? (_addStudentCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
                {
                    //Create new student
                    Student student = new Student();

                    //Set new student's properties
                    //TODO: Add ID value
                    student.Name = Name;
                    student.Surname = Surname;
                    student.ParentName = ParentName;
                    student.ParentSurname = ParentSurname;
                    student.ClassLetter = Convert.ToChar(ClassLetter.ToUpper());
                    student.ClassNumber = NumberConvertor(ClassNumber);
                    student.Class = Appender(ClassLetter, ClassNumber);
                    student.Number = Int32.Parse(Number);
                    student.Age = AgeConvertor(Age);
                    student.Barcode = Barcode;
                    student.ID = 6;
                    student.LastCheckIn = DateTime.Now;
                    student.DateOfCreation = DateTime.Now;

                    //TODO: ADD student to DATABASE
                    FakeStudentDataLayer.Add(student);
                }));
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Here is the AddView

```
<Grid>
    <!--DataContext-->
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <dc:UserDummyData/>
    </Grid.DataContext>

    <!--Student TextBoxes-->
    <TextBlock x:Name="StudentNameWaterMark"
               Grid.Column="2"
               Text="{x:Static p:Resources.Name}"
               Style="{StaticResource WaterMarkStyle}"
               Visibility="{Binding
                    ElementName=StudentNameContentTextBox, 
                    Path=Text.IsEmpty, Converter={StaticResource 
                    WaterMarkRemover}}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="StudentNameContentTextBox"
             Grid.Column="2"
             Text="{Binding Name}"
             Width="{Binding ElementName=StudentNameWaterMark,
                Path=Width}"
             Style="{StaticResource BasicTextBoxTextStyle}"
             Background="Transparent">
    </TextBox>
    <TextBlock Name="StudentSurnameWaterMark"
               Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"
               Text="{x:Static p:Resources.Surname}"
               Style="{StaticResource WaterMarkStyle}"
               Visibility="{Binding
                    ElementName=StudentSurnameContentTextBox,
                    Path=Text.IsEmpty, Converter={StaticResource 
                    WaterMarkRemover}}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="StudentSurnameContentTextBox"
             Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"
             Text="{Binding Surname}"
             Width="{Binding ElementName=StudentSurnameWaterMark,
                Path=Width}"
             Style="{StaticResource BasicTextBoxTextStyle}"
             Background="Transparent">
    </TextBox>

    <!--Parent TextBoxes-->
    <TextBlock x:Name="ParentNameWaterMark"
               Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"
               Text="{x:Static p:Resources.ParentName}"
               Style="{StaticResource WaterMarkStyle}"
               Visibility="{Binding 
                    ElementName=ParentNameContentTextBox, 
                    Path=Text.IsEmpty, Converter={StaticResource 
                    WaterMarkRemover}}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="ParentNameContentTextBox"
             Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"
             Text="{Binding ParentName}"
             Width="{Binding ElementName=ParentNameWaterMark,
                Path=Width}"
             Style="{StaticResource BasicTextBoxTextStyle}"
             Background="Transparent">
    </TextBox>
    <TextBlock x:Name="ParentSurnameWaterMark"
               Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3"
               Text="{x:Static p:Resources.ParentSurname}"
               Style="{StaticResource WaterMarkStyle}"
               Visibility="{Binding 
                      ElementName=ParentSurnameContentTextBox, 
                      Path=Text.IsEmpty, Converter={StaticResource 
                      WaterMarkRemover}}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="ParentSurnameContentTextBox"
             Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3"
             Text="{Binding ParentSurname}"
             Width="{Binding ElementName=ParentSurnameWaterMark,
                Path=Width}"
             Style="{StaticResource BasicTextBoxTextStyle}"
             Background="Transparent">
    </TextBox>

    <!--Student Details TextBoxes-->
    <TextBlock x:Name="AgeWaterMark"           
               Grid.Column="5"
               Text="{x:Static p:Resources.Age}"
               Style="{StaticResource WaterMarkStyle}"
               Visibility="{Binding 
                      ElementName=AgeContentTextBox, 
                      Path=Text.IsEmpty, Converter={StaticResource 
                      WaterMarkRemover}}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="AgeContentTextBox"
             Grid.Column="5"
             Text="{Binding Age}"
             Width="{Binding ElementName=AgeWaterMark,
                Path=Width}"
             Style="{StaticResource BasicTextBoxTextStyle}"
             Background="Transparent"/>

    <Grid Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock x:Name="GradeNumberWaterMark"
                       Text="{x:Static p:Resources.GradeNumber}"
                       Style="{StaticResource GradeWaterMarkStyle}"
                       Visibility="{Binding 
                            ElementName=GradeNumberContentTextBox, 
                            Path=Text.IsEmpty, Converter={StaticResource 
                            WaterMarkRemover}}"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="GradeNumberContentTextBox"
                     Width="{Binding ElementName=GradeNumberWaterMark,
                        Path=Width}"
                     Text="{Binding ClassNumber}"
                     Style="{StaticResource TextBoxTextStyle}"
                     Background="Transparent"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="5">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock x:Name="GradeLetterWaterMark"
                       Text="{x:Static p:Resources.GradeLetter}"
                       Style="{StaticResource GradeWaterMarkStyle}"
                       Visibility="{Binding 
                            ElementName=GradeLetterContentTextBox, 
                            Path=Text.IsEmpty, Converter={StaticResource 
                            WaterMarkRemover}}"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="GradeLetterContentTextBox"
                     Width="{Binding ElementName=GradeLetterWaterMark,
                        Path=Width}"
                     Text="{Binding ClassLetter}"
                     Style="{StaticResource TextBoxTextStyle}"
                     Background="Transparent"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

    <TextBlock x:Name="NumberWaterMark"
               Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="2"
               Text="{x:Static p:Resources.NumberInClass}"
               Style="{StaticResource WaterMarkStyle}"
               Visibility="{Binding
                    ElementName=NumberContentTextBox, 
                    Path=Text.IsEmpty, Converter={StaticResource 
                    WaterMarkRemover}}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="NumberContentTextBox"
             Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="2"  
             Width="{Binding ElementName=NumberWaterMark,
                    Path=Width}"
             Text="{Binding Number}"
             Style="{StaticResource BasicTextBoxTextStyle}"
             Background="Transparent"/>

    <TextBlock x:Name="BarcodeWaterMark"
               Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="3"
               Text="{x:Static p:Resources.Barcode}"
               Style="{StaticResource WaterMarkStyle}"
               Visibility="{Binding
                    ElementName=BarcodeContentTextBox, 
                    Path=Text.IsEmpty, Converter={StaticResource 
                    WaterMarkRemover}}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="BarcodeContentTextBox"
             Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="3"
             Width="{Binding ElementName=BarcodeWaterMark,
                    Path=Width}"
             Text="{Binding Barcode}"
             Style="{StaticResource BarcodeTextBoxTextStyle}"
             Background="Transparent"/>

    <!--Buttons-->
    <Grid Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="6">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="1"
                Content="{x:Static p:Resources.Add}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
                Command="{Binding NewStudentCommand}"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="2"
                Content="{x:Static p:Resources.Clear}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Here is the ShowView

```
<Grid>
    <!--DataContext-->
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <dc:UserDummyData/>
    </Grid.DataContext> 
    <!--DataGrid-->         
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          CanUserAddRows="True"
          CanUserDeleteRows="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding FakeStudentDataLayer}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.sName}"
                                Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.sSurname}"
                                Binding="{Binding Surname}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.sAge}"
                                Binding="{Binding Age}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.sGrade}"
                                Binding="{Binding Class}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.sNumber}"
                                Binding="{Binding Number}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.LastCheckIn}"
                                Binding="{Binding LastCheckIn}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Note: If  I put a the code from the ShowView in the AddView then everything works but if they are like this - one two separate views, the DataGrid does not update.

EDIT: I tried making a more simpler project using the same structure. Unbelievably it worked I did not make anything different as in this. The difference between the new sampler project and this one is that I use more basic model - only two properties. and I don't have localization if that matters. So my question is why does it work on a smaller project and not in thes one.

Comment: by using `ObservableCollection` and databinding, UI should've been updated automatically whenever item added or removed from collection. So, what is the problem? post some relevant codes showing the actual problem

Comment: and what platform is this? WPF, winform, ASP.NET, else?

Comment: @har07 Yes it updates when I used the same view for adding and showing the objects in the collection, but as I said I have two views one for adding and one for showing the data

Comment: @Gorge - As long as you are adding to same `ObservableCollection` and binding is done with same instance, views will be updated. Post relevant code if its not so that anyone can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

What do you exactly mean by force update? If you mean by adding the data, try using scaffolding

http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/aspnet-scaffolding-overview

Comment: I'm using WPF not ASP.NET I think that this does not help me much

Answer (score 0):

I´m not sure how your code exactly looks, but i think you got a Window, containing multiple views, your Window got a MainViewModel for example, the views inside got their own viewmodels.
If the MainViewModel creates and handles the other views, then it got instances of them, and is able to call methods there.

So maybe your problem is that you want to know how communication between the viewmodels could be done?

Here a small example of what i´m thinking of.
If you got a MainViewModel, a DataAddViewModel, and a ShowViewModel. 
The MainViewModel creates the DataAddViewModel, and the ShowViewModel.
DataAddViewModel has an event, which is triggered when new data is inserted.
ShowViewModel has a binding to the Listview or whatever, and a public method which triggers that binding.

Notice : The following is just an example.

Possible Event in **DataAddViewModel**

```
public event EventHandler DataAddedEvent;

private void RaiseDataAddedEvent()
{
    var handler = this.DataAddedEvent;
    if (handler == null) return;
    handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Possible event registration and handling in **MainViewModel**

```
var _ShowVm = new ShowViewModel();
var _AddVm = new DataAddViewModel();
_addVm.DataAddedEvent += OnDataAdded;

//Notify our ShowViewModel about the new data
private void OnDataAdded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        _ShowVm.DataAdded();
}
```

public method in **ShowViewModel**

```
public void DataAdded(){
    RaisePropertyChanged("NameOfMyBinding");
}
```

Comment: Take a look at my code. I'll see if I could add that to my project

Comment: looks like you have only one view model for two views. maybe you work with two instances of dummydata. so if you add data, you add it to only the instance which add data is using. EDIT: you also don't raise a property changed event when you add data to the collection. For that you got to register for CollectionChanged event of the ObservableCollection. That event is triggered, when you add or remove elements of the collection

Comment: I did not create view instances intentionally, so is it possible to access directly DummyData view model or I must use instances. And can you show me how to work with CollectionChanged event

Comment: As far as i know, if you set the datacontext in xaml like you did, it automatically creates an instance of it. In your case that would mean that you got two instances of dummydata. Think of my approach to instantiate the viewmodels in a mainviewmodel, and set the datacontext of them to the same instance of dummydata.

Comment: well if you are right then why when I create a sample project and do the same the views get notified

Comment: because if you got only one view, there is only one instance of DummyData.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the problem comes from you using two separate instances of `UserDummyData`. In both the Show view and the Add view you set the `DataContext` like this:

```
<Grid.DataContext>
    <dc:UserDummyData/>
</Grid.DataContext>
```

Both of those lines construct a new `UserDummyData` object. Thus, when you add data to one of them, the data is not added in the other. You should do something like this:

```
<Grid ... DataContext="{x:Static p:Resources.MyUserDummyDataInstance}"/>
```

Then, when you add students to the one `UserDummyData`, both views will show the new students, because both of their lists (which are, in fact, the same list) will have the new student.